# Android XML layout set attributes of children?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is a quick, probably yes/no question, but I'm trying to pretty up my xml and I'm wondering if there is a way to have a parent layout override the children's layout_width property? that way I can omit layout_width from every child node, for fewer lines of code?

Comment: Is the parent your own custom class? If so, the answer is "yes", as `TableRow` does this.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's interesting, I thought it was a 'fixed' thing that every xml element should have layout_width & layout_height. Is `TableRow` an exception to this case, or are they other such views as well?

Comment: @ChrisvinJem: `TableLayout` and `TableRow` are the only ones that I know of that set a default `layout_width` and `layout_height` for its children. It wasn't a widespread technique, and as a result I don't know the details of how those classes are doing what they are doing. But, the source is available, and so a sufficiently motivated person could figure out the mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short: No.
For layout width is requeired property.